# Как отобразить элемент, когда у него определён DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вьюмодели:

```
  public class Notes : BaseViewModel
  {
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> NoteLines { get; } 
  }

  public class SomePage : BaseViewModel
  {
    public Notes Notes { get; set; }
  }
```

Datatemplate:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="local:Notes">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
      <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding NoteLines}"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="local:SomePage">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <SomeElement Grid.Column="0"/>
      <SomeElement Grid.Column="1"/>
      <!-- тут какой то способ отобразить Notes -->
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Не понимаю, как отобразить свойство `Notes` и как потом например экземпляр `SomePage` отобразить.

Плюс, не уверен, а как будет передаваться `DataContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый вечер! Используйте **MarkupExtension** `x:Type` для указания типа `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomePage}">
```

Для того, чтобы `DataTemplate` от класса `Nodes` подхватился, используйте `ContentControl`. То есть, вместо вашего комментария напишите следующее:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Nodes}" />
```

`DataTemplate` автоматически подхватится.

Из байндингов можно заметить, что в датаконтексте этих темплейтов лежат сами вьюмодели, то есть:

Для `<DataTemplate DataType="local:SomePage">`
`DataContext` = `SomePage`

Для `<DataTemplate DataType="local:Notes">`
`DataContext` = `Notes`

По вашему примеру у меня получилось примерно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `x:Type` неочевиден совсем, спасибо за помощь.